I have undifind error when choseo file javascript
Can't move or copy file
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupd') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = './' + files.filetoupload.name;
      console.log(oldpath);
      console.log(newpath);
      fs.copyFile(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('<form action="fileupd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);

I try to get source file path and selcted file name
but i have below err
undefined
./undefined

Can you try this instead: var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
